# Current.User.Identity.Name in asp.net application is correct but it is Empty in wcf Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have two Web Applications: One Asp.net and one WCF.
Forms Authentication is configured in both , machine key and auth cookies are set well to maintain Single Sign On between the two applications.

The problem is when I logged in Successfully to asp.net, identity is returned ok.

But When Request come from asp.net to any wcf service, **the identity is returned null?** **The WCF Service am Calling for example: client.GetUser()
Did not recognize the current logged user from the asp.net login**

Below are both web.config Files:

**asp.net web.config:**

```
<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
 <authentication mode="Forms">
<forms enableCrossAppRedirects="true" loginUrl="~/Pages/Logon/Logon.aspx"  name=".ADAuthCookie"  ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" timeout="180" protection="Encryption">
</forms>
</authentication> 
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<machineKey validationKey="A5A2B2DD6DF15890818D3CF7884FA4E0C0F4040B85338DAFE559B35EB84F4258" decryptionKey="DEA92973CA91FA1931227F14D5F4FF161602312A816BFA28A1529DE93F6993D3" validation="SHA1"/>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>

     <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,         System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,         PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionStringName="ActiveDirectory_ConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<identity impersonate="true"/>

</system.web>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecure" />
   </basicHttpBinding>
   </binding>

   <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:2013/WCFServices/App/Secure.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISecure"
    contract="Secure.ISecure" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecure" />
   </client>
```

**WCF Web.config:**

```
   <System.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms enableCrossAppRedirects="true" loginUrl="~/Pages/Logon/Logon.aspx"  name=".ADAuthCookie"  ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" timeout="180" protection="Encryption">
</forms>
</authentication> 

<machineKey validationKey="A5A2B2DD6DF15890818D3CF7884FA4E0C0F4040B85338DAFE559B35EB84F4258" decryptionKey="DEA92973CA91FA1931227F14D5F4FF161602312A816BFA28A1529DE93F6993D3" validation="SHA1"/>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>

     <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,         System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,         PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionStringName="ActiveDirectory_ConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
</system.web>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecure" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>


  <endpoint address="http://localhost:2013/WCFServices/App/Secure.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISecure"
    contract="Security.ISecure" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecure" />

  <system.serviceModel>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Can you please  tell me what is the problem?

[Asp.net Configuration in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nke52.jpg) 
[WCF Service Configuration in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zinj.jpg)

Comment: In the bindings configuration you do not set any authentication scheme. i.e.:
`<binding name="WindowsAuthenticationBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>`

Comment: What is the working binding configuration  in case of Enabling Forms Based Authentication without Https ,  only using http.??